# Can anyone explain why 1 of 4 calendars shows Time=?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have 4 calendars, startCal, endCal, reminderCal and today. today simply gets a Calendar.getInstance() for the current date/time, whereas the 3 others go through the same method for selecting date&time using Androids date/time pickers.

startCal and endCal are working just fine
    if(startCal.after(endCal)){ // handle error }

however, reminderCal.before(today) doesn't return true, even when I purposely set the reminderCal before the current date.

Also, when printing all the times, the reminderCal doesn't have any time (Time=?) and areFieldsSet=false, but if I submit a second time the time gets updated, although the before() method still doesn't work!

Everything seems to work except for the the else if (reminderCal.before(today))

```
public boolean validInput(){
    if(startCal.after(endCal)){
        //THIS WORKS
        timeError.setText(getString(R.string.error_event_end_early));
        isOk = false;
        Log.e(TAG, "validInput: Event ends before it starts");
    }

    if(hasReminder.isChecked()){
        if(reminderDate.getText().toString().matches("")) {
            // THIS WORKS
            reminderError.setText(R.string.error_no_reminder);
            isOk = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "validInput: No reminder set");
        } else if (reminderCal.before(today)){
            // THIS DOESN'T WORK. Why?
            reminderError.setText(R.string.error_reminder_early);
            isOk = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "validInput: Reminder too early " + reminderCal.toString());
        }  else if(reminderCal.after(startCal)){
            //THIS WORKS
            reminderError.setText(R.string.error_reminder_late);
            isOk = false;
            Log.e(TAG, "validInput: Reminder too late");
        }
    return isOk;
}


    Log.e(TAG, "Debugging: \n" +
            "strCalandar: " + startCal.toString() + "\n" +
            "endCalandar: " + endCal.toString() + "\n" +
            "remCalandar: " + reminderCal.toString() + "\n" +
            "todCalandar: " + today.toString() + "\n");
}
```

today = Calander.getInstance(); with no further adjustments. The other calendars get the date/time from these methods.

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(final EditText text, final Calendar cal){
    Log.d(TAG, "showDatePickerDialog: Open");
    DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
    ((DatePickerFragment) datePicker).setOnDateChosenListener(new DatePickerFragment.OnDateChosenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChosen(int year, int month, int day) {
            text.setText(String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", day, month, year));
            cal.set(year, month, day);
        }
    });
    datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(final EditText text, final Calendar cal){
    Log.d(TAG, "showTimePickerDialog: Open");
    DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
    ((TimePickerFragment) timePicker).setOnTimeChosenListener(new TimePickerFragment.OnTimeChosenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChosen(int hour, int min) {
            text.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, min));
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        }
    });
    timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");
}
```

Output in Logcat:

```
strCalandar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1566152201478,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",mRawOffset=0,mEarliestRawOffset=0,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=242],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=33,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=230,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=16,SECOND=41,MILLISECOND=478,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
endCalandar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1566152201478,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",mRawOffset=0,mEarliestRawOffset=0,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=242],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=33,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=230,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=7,HOUR_OF_DAY=19,MINUTE=16,SECOND=41,MILLISECOND=478,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
remCalandar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",mRawOffset=0,mEarliestRawOffset=0,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=242],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=7,WEEK_OF_YEAR=31,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_YEAR=214,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=18,SECOND=41,MILLISECOND=478,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
todCalandar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1562775401478,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/London",mRawOffset=0,mEarliestRawOffset=0,mUseDst=true,mDstSavings=3600000,transitions=242],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=28,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=191,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=16,SECOND=41,MILLISECOND=478,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

reminderCal.before(today) should return true if reminder date is set before current date

Comment: It’s still a lot of code. [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: Stripped it further and separated the code. I don't get why reminderCal gets time=? while the rest have time set to timeinmillis. I'm guessing thats why the before/after doen't work for reminderCal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have tried to explain it in this part of the docs:

> **`set(f, value)`** changes calendar field `f` to `value`. In addition, it sets an internal member variable to indicate that
>   calendar field `f` has been changed. Although calendar field `f` is
>   changed immediately, the calendar's time value in milliseconds is not
>   recomputed until the next call to `get()`, `getTime()`,
>   `getTimeInMillis()`, `add()`, or `roll()` is made. Thus, multiple
>   calls to `set()` do not trigger multiple, unnecessary computations. As
>   a result of changing a calendar field using `set()`, other calendar
>   fields may also change, depending on the calendar field, the calendar
>   field value, and the calendar system. In addition, `get(f)` will not
>   necessarily return value set by the call to the `set` method after the
>   calendar fields have been recomputed. The specifics are determined by
>   the concrete calendar class.
>
> *Example:* Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to August 31, 1999. Calling set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER) sets the date to September 31, 1999. This is a temporary internal representation that
>   resolves to October 1, 1999 if getTime()is then called. However, a
>   call to set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30) before the call to getTime()
>   sets the date to September 30, 1999, since no recomputation occurs
>   after set() itself.

So since you call `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);` and `cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);`, the time gets temporarily undefined, which is why the question mark is printed from `toString`.

I have not been able to reproduce the reported behaviour of `before` and `after`, but it seems reasonable to assume that they also don’t work correctly until `get` or one of the mentioned `getXxx` methods is called.

This is only one of the very confusing aspects of the design of the `Calendar` class. The good solution is to switch to using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks, fixed the error (which was unrelated to the Time=? as it turns out), but useful information anyway :)